# $2(v_{0}^2 - v_{0y}^2)d_{y} = 2v_{0y}d_{x}\sqrt{v_{0}^2-v_{0y}^2} + ad_x^{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

> $$2(v_{0}^2 - v_{0y}^2)d_{y} = 2v_{0y}d_{x}\sqrt{v_{0}^2-v_{0y}^2} + ad_x^{2}$$

All variables except $v_{0y}$ are given. How can I find $v_{0y}$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_{0y}=X,v_0=p,d_y=q,d_x=r$.

Then, we have
$$2(p^2 - X^2)q-ar^2 = 2Xr\sqrt{p^2-X^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \left(2(p^2 - X^2)q-ar^2\right)^2=\left(2Xr\sqrt{p^2-X^2}\right)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow (4q^2+4r^2)X^4+(4aqr^2-8p^2q^2-4p^2r^2)X^2+a^2r^4-4ap^2qr^2+4p^4q^2=0$$
Now set $y=X^2$ and solve for $y$. Note that this is a necessary condition.